# How do I export my favourites from Chrome to the stock browser?

Tags: stock-browser, bookmarks

I have been searching online for a way but couldn't find anything.  How do I copy my Favourites from the latest version of Chrome Android to the stock browser on my Samsung Galaxy S3?  I want to be able to open my list of Favourites from within the stock browser.  Any way?

OS: 4.1.1

Comment: I know you can export Chrome bookmarks using a desktop version (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en-GB), but I do not believe that the stock browser can import bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this with syncing your bookmarks over google account?
I know that stock browser reads the bookmarks synced with google account when logged in. 
If you log into google using chrome browser, syncing bookmarks and then logging into google using stock browser should get your bookmarks there.
Can't test it because I am currently on 4.2.2 and don't have Chrome for android installed so this is just a guess how it could be done.

### **edit**

When you first start your chrome browser it asks you right away to login into your google account.
If you have done that it asks you the same question as in the desktop version - whether to synchronize things like passwords, bookmarks etc. between your chrome instances.
If you have done the first thing and answered the following question with "yes everything" or just "yes" with a marked checkbox for bookmarks you're pretty much set up.
If you don't have this done yet you can reconfigure synchronization in chrome settings.

Now if you take a look into the bookmarks section of chrome you should see some folders like "mobile bookmarks", "other bookmarks", "desktop bookmarks" (due to my german version the titles may differ a bit).
Every bookmark saved under "desktop bookmarks" will be synchronized back to your google account.
If you open your stock android browser some minutes later and login to your google account when asked you will see your google email address as a folder/category inside bookmarks section containing your bookmarks from chrome.
Even if you will install i.e. a chrome browser on your desktop some day you will end up with your bookmarks/tabs/passwords/... beeing pulled from your google account once you login.

Here are some screenshots (as I already mentioned they're unfortunately from my german version):

[image: chrome sync settings]
[image: chrome desktop bookmarks folder]
[image: storing bookmarks in folder]
[image: created bookmark]
[image: automatically pulled bookmarks inside stock browser]

Comment: You're right - I did this over the weekend on stock 4.1.2. You need to ensure you have "sync internet" enabled in your phone settings.  If you get an error enabling "sync internet" you need to resolve that first; it may be because you have used a passphrase within chrome to encrypt bookmarks etc - you'll need to stop that and encrypt using your google credentials (this is the other of the two options on the desktop version of chrome).

Comment: I don't have desktop access.  Can this be done with just my phone?

Comment: I think that should be possible. Stock android browser fetches bookmarks from google account automatically (different lables > "local" / "<your googleaccount email>"). So if you can get your android chrome browser to sync its bookmarks to google you will imo end up seeing your bookmarks of your google account inside of the stock browsers bookmarks (at least in 4.2.2 browser). If you want to see what is there to get synced between your chrome browser(s) etc. see [here](https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync). Correct me when I am wrong due to my missing chrome for android knowledge.

Comment: Can you give me a step-by-step.  I'm lost.

Comment: @verve Just downloaded google chrome on my android phone to test it myself. Check my edited answer.

Comment: What about [Phone 2 Google Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lg.valle.phone2chrome) and [Google Chrome 2 Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chrometophone) ?

Comment: @felix: I don't have any desktop bookmarks in Chrome so how will it work?  I only have stuff under mobile bookmarks.

Comment: I want to transfer mobile to mobile bookmarks.

Comment: I have my Chrome bookmarks synced but when I go into stock and sign into Gmail I don't see my bookmarks.  :-(